# Why are galalxies spiral?

Tags: galaxies, galaxy-rotation-curve, galaxy-clusters

In every picture we see that galaxies are spiral, why so? are there any other shapes possible?

Comment: Welcome to [physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com)! Have you checked online, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy ?

Comment: Not every picture of a galaxy is spiral. There are elliptical galaxies out there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, other shapes are possible. For example, here is a picture from [NASA](https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/ap040616.html) of M87, an elliptical galaxy:

[image]

It doesn’t look spiral *at all*.

Comment: Minor quibble: that picture is from the Canada-France-Hawaii Telescope, not from NASA.